# Chrome policy "ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox" not working

Tags: windows, google-chrome, phpstorm, protocols, xdebug

I am using the library https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol/ to get links to my IDE (PHPStorm) from the browser (Chrome). Everytime xdebug prints a warning, it attaches a link with an href like this:

```
phpstorm://open?file={filepath}&line={line}
```

[image: xdebug_link]

That works perfect. The problem is that every time I click in the link I get a pop-up like this:
[image: popup]

I have tried following the steps I found here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1481851/disable-chrome-to-ask-for-confirmation-to-open-external-application-everytime

After enabling that [policy](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox) in the register of windows, and validating it also in my browser I still have the same pop-up without the checkbox to allow this protocol forever.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you want to open your url handler over a "http" connection.

But you get only the square if you have a "https" connection.

You can solve your problem if you set a rule, that your "http" connection is trusted.

For chrome write "chrome://flags/" in your address bar and write your url into the option "Insecure origins treated as secure" and set this to enable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMPvy.png)

Answer (score 2):

The `External​Protocol​Dialog​Show​Always​Open​Checkbox` does work on `https` websites only.

You can instead add you protocol `phpstorm://*` to Chrome's [`URLAllowlist`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#URLAllowlist), for example via the Windows registry :

[image: Windows registry]

The user will not see the popup at all and the software will open automatically.